# Rotate camera when its tablet[XAMARIN FORMS]

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-camera

I need the camera to rotate to portrait when I'm using a tablet. I need this [image: landscape mode]  to become this [image: portrait mode]

I have tried changing the SetTransform method below, but with no luck at all. All the attempts resulted in the image being stretched or half the size of the screen when it rotates.
here are the methods that I'm using.

```
 public void ContinueOpenCamera()
    {
        SetUpCamera();
        SetTransform();
        var manager = (CameraManager)Context.GetSystemService(Context.CameraService);
        manager.OpenCamera(cameraId, new CameraStateListener(this), null);
    }

    private void SetUpCamera()
    {
        var manager = (CameraManager)Context.GetSystemService(Context.CameraService);
        var cameraList = manager.GetCameraIdList();
        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < cameraList.Length; ++i)
            {
                cameraId = cameraList[i];
                var characteristics = manager.GetCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                var facing = (Integer)characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.LensFacing);

                if (facing == null || facing != Facing)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var map = (StreamConfigurationMap)characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.ScalerStreamConfigurationMap);
                if (map == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                sensorOrientation = (int)characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.SensorOrientation);
                textureViewSize = !Config.Rotated
                    ? GetBestSize(height, width, map.GetOutputSizes(Class.FromType(typeof(SurfaceTexture))))
                    : GetBestSize(width, height, map.GetOutputSizes(Class.FromType(typeof(SurfaceTexture))));

                if (sensorOrientation == 90 || sensorOrientation == 270)
                {
                    textureViewSize = new Size(textureViewSize.Height, textureViewSize.Width);
                }

                paint.StrokeWidth = System.Math.Min(width, height) / 300;
                greenTextPaint.TextSize = blueTextPaint.TextSize = paint.StrokeWidth * 15;
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
    }
 private Size GetBestSize(int width, int height, IEnumerable<Size> sizes)
    {

        var dw = (double)width;
        var dh = (double)height;
        var targetAspect = dw / dh;
        var sorted = sizes.Select(size => new Tuple<double, Size>(
            System.Math.Max(
                System.Math.Abs(dw / size.Width - 1),
                System.Math.Abs(dh / size.Height - 1)
            ), size))
            .OrderBy(value => value.Item1).ToArray();
        var best = sorted[0];
        var bestAspect = System.Math.Abs(best.Item2.Width / best.Item2.Height - targetAspect);
        for (int i = 1; i < sorted.Length; ++i)
        {
            var current = sorted[i];
            if (System.Math.Abs(current.Item1 - best.Item1) > 1e-10)
                break;
            var aspect = System.Math.Abs(current.Item2.Width / current.Item2.Height - targetAspect);
            if (bestAspect - aspect > 1e-10)
            {
                best = current;
                bestAspect = aspect;
            }
        }
        return best.Item2;
    }
  private void SetTransform()
    {

        var matrix = new Matrix();
        var viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
        var scale = System.Math.Max(
            (float)width / textureViewSize.Width,
            (float)height / textureViewSize.Height);
        var bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0,
            textureViewSize.Width * scale, textureViewSize.Height * scale);

        bitmapScale = System.Math.Max(
               System.Math.Max(
                   bufferRect.Width() / MaxSize,
                   bufferRect.Height() / MaxSize
                   ),
               1
               );
        bitmapSize = new Size(
                Convert.ToInt32(bufferRect.Width() / bitmapScale),
                Convert.ToInt32(bufferRect.Height() / bitmapScale));

        pixels = new int[bitmapSize.Width * bitmapSize.Height];
        bytes = new byte[pixels.Length * 4];

        bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmapSize.Width, bitmapSize.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);

        matrix.SetRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.Fill);



        textureView.SetTransform(matrix);
        viewRect.Dispose();
        bufferRect.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: there are [many existing questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+api+set+camera+orientation+site:stackoverflow.com) on this subject.

Comment: my problem here is that the device rotation will be always portrait. In the tablet version the camera is in landscape mode. I want it to be on portrait also. The link you provided, is the search I've been doing it before asking here.

Comment: Why not just lock it to portrait?